# FIFA 15 online play

Tags: xbox-network, fifa-15

Can friends play together against computer on FIFA 15? Or is it only against real players? I've tried looking an I'm not sure this is  possible. Any FIFA gurus out there?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking about playing with a friend with 2 different consoles not in the same network against the computer. The answers is no, you can't sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about playing with a friend that sits next to you and using a controller - sure you can play a friendly match against the computer or start a tournament.

Comment: I think he meant online.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I do this all the time.

Just select the same side when in the controller setup.

Comment: Even when online? Where/how can you set it up this way?